# high side mosfet offset voltage in Phase shifted full bridge converter

Tags: phase

I am working on phase shifted full bridge converter. The input voltage of it is 300 V.

The issue is I am able to see offset voltage (shown in fig below) in the gate to source pulses during turn-off period of high side MOSFET when input voltage of 300 V or even less than that applied to it.

Without input voltage applied the gate to source pulses are clear and there is no offset. This issue was happening only on high side MOSFETs but at the low side MOSFETs the things are not same as upper MOSFET there is no offset voltage.

**Why is this happening?**

[image]

Comment: HI Vinay and welcome.  How are you making this measurement?  If your scope probe is on the high side gate, where is scope ground?

Comment: Hi John, I am measuring voltage across gate and source of mosfet directly using differential probe ,since the DSO which I am using is non-isolated channels. But the Image which I shown in the above is only on high side mosfet for low side mosfet with same differential probe there is no offset during turn-off period.

Comment: I think it might be a measurement problem.  Try using two separate DC probes, one on source and one on gate, and use the scope's math function to subtract the two curves or invert one and add.

Answer (score 1):

Might be that the diff probe has a common mode rejection problem...what probe are you using?
If it is common mode then supply a voltage far less than 300V should make it go away. Try 30V for example.

Comment: Yeah with less input voltage the spike which it shoots is very less but this offset I am able to see only in high side mosfet and only when input voltage is given, without input voltage the pulses are clear. There is no offset in my low side mosfet even with input voltage when I have done measurement using same differential probe .The differential probe is tektronix p5200A